# Cyanogen play store access

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod

If cyanogen forks off and comes up as a direct competitor to Googles version,can google prevent android apps from working on cyanogen or since both are android based all would android apps would work perfectly fine with cyanogen version of android.

Comment: Thank you,What about the apps,can an android app developer put up the same app he has created for Google play store to say the Amazon or a cyanogen App Store.Or would it require quite a bit of work before its compatible .

Comment: That's done all the time: many apps are available in multiple places, like Playstore, F-Droid, Aptoide, Amazon. Just check [my app lists](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists) if you don't believe it. Plus, Playstore can even be accessed without GApps. Just [search this site for "NOGAPPS"](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=nogapps), which is how I do it on my CyanogenMod devices :)

Answer (score 1):

Android is an open-source project. Kindle Fire works with its own store and it's making a lot of money. So no, Google won't forbid you using the Android - without Google.